# How do i add a web-view to my Amazon Lex chatbot on Messenger?

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I would like to add this [webview](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webview/) feature to my Amazon Lex chatbot on Facebook Messenger but I can't figure out how. The reason I want to add webview is that I need the user to select multiple checkboxes.

Comment: Should be possible, though I haven't used it myself. Can you be more specific than "I can't figure out how"? What have you tried?